# Emailable-report.html is not found when I run my test with mvn clean then mvn test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, testng

I'm using maven with testNG, but when I use "mvn clean", it cleans the target folder, then I use "mvn test" to run my test cases and send email with the result I got error "java.io.FileNotFoundException" as the report is generated after everything is done.
I used SuiteListener and ListenerTest and also tried to send the email from AfterSuite and AfterClass but I got the same error because the report is being generated after all the annotations and listeners are done.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG reports are generated in the reporting phase.
All the TestNG annotations are processed during the execution phase and so all the methods that are annotated with configuration annnotations such as `@AfterSuite` (or) `@AfterTest` get executed during the execution phase.

That explains why you see the exception.

If you would like to access the artifacts that were generated during the reporting phase, you could build an implementation of the TestNG listener interface `org.testng.IExecutionListener` which will be invoked by TestNG after the reporting phase, but just before TestNG exits.

But you would need to make proper assumptions in terms of where the report files are going to be generated because this interface methods namely `onExecutionStart()` and `onExecutionFinish()` are parameterless and so wouldn't know where the reports would be available at.